# Remove double quotes from String when is needed

Tags: string, go, trim

Hello I'm working with Golang and I have to remove the double quotes from a string, when it is required, in the cases when I don't have double quotes, I don't have to do this trim.

For example, when I have `""HI""` I have to apply the trim, but no with "HI". I'm using the next code:

```
strings.Trim(stringVal, "\"")
```

It worked, but then I'm using a `strings.EqualFold(stringVal, "HI")` validation and if I apply trim to a normal string like "HI", the comparison is wrong.

Is there any way to do the trim, just with strings with double quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: I think Regex will be better suited for this,

Answer (score 2):

If the string has the unwanted prefix and suffix, then chop them off using a slice expression:

```
func trim(s string) string {
    if strings.HasPrefix(s, `""`) && strings.HasSuffix(s, `""`) && len(s) > 2 {
        return s[1 : len(s)-1]
    }
    return s
}
```

Example:

```
fmt.Println(trim(`"Hi"`))       // prints "Hi"
fmt.Println(trim(`""Hi""`))     // prints "Hi"
fmt.Println(trim(`""""`))       // prints ""
fmt.Println(trim(`""`))         // prints ""
fmt.Println(trim(`"\j\u\n\k"`)) // prints "\j\u\n\k"
```

[Run the code on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iIJcRyoIjuH).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "strconv"

func main() {
   s, e := strconv.Unquote(`"HI"`)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(s == "HI")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strconv#Unquote